# Purpose and function of "$@" in tclsh "$0" "$@"

Tags: tcl, sh

I have searched long and hard but could only find a short explanation that `$@` expands something.

Could someone please explain or provide me with a link to a detailed explanation of the purpose of `"$@"` as the second argument to

```
tclsh "$0" "$@"
```

Also, I am looking over someone's script, and they have the following:

```
exec tclsh `basename $0` $*
```

What does `$*` do in this case?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are part of the bootstrapping stanza often used in Tcl scripts. Let's get the whole stanza:

```
#!/bin/sh
# A Tcl comment, whose contents don't matter \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
```

The first line runs the script as a Bourne shell program (bash and many other shells work the same way; it's a POSIX specification). The second line is ignored by the shell. The third line  *replaces* the shell with tclsh with the arguments that were passed to the shell. The `"$0"` is the name of the script, and the `"$@"` is magic for all the arguments with appropriate quoting. (You might also see `${1+"$@"}` which is a workaround for evil bugs in some older shells.) You can theoretically omit the `exec` here, but that means that the rest of the script will be interpreted by the system shell on termination of the Tcl program; that's probably not what you want. Finally, when tclsh sees those lines above, it thinks that they're *all* comments; Tcl comments start at a `#` at the beginning of a line (or with spaces in front) and continue to the end of the line *after allowing for line continuation markers*. (Yes, this is unusual. Useful though.)

The form with `basename` is rather unusual, in that it is removing any path to the file being executed. This is probably not a good idea, as it can mean that tclsh doesn't know exactly which file to execute. Similarly, the `$*` is also almost but not right (it expands to all the arguments, but *without* quoting; if users pass in filenames with spaces in, you'll soon see the difference!)

Finally, these days it is considered best practice to use a starting stanza like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
```

It's shorter, far less error-prone, and just as standardized as the shell.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually not Tcl, it is bash. It was (or is) not uncommon to use `#!/bin/bash \` on the first line. Tcl will ignore the next line too (because of the `\` at the end of the line), bash will execute it.

About the $* and $@, I suggest reading the man page of [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (under Special Parameters). `` ` `` is for command substitution, similar to Tcl's `[` and `]`

Comment: bourne shell (`sh`) actually, not bash.  The `#!/bin/sh \` style is less popular now; see http://wiki.tcl.tk/812 for the modern wisdom.

Comment: thank you @evilotto. I never used this method of invoking tclsh, I always modified the path to tclsh (witch was on all unix systems where I used it in /usr/bin/tclsh, only for cgi on windows (local tests) I had to modify it.